# How do I add security to my WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Such as two factor authentication, 3rd party OAuth, Connecting to LDAP.

I have added the above security to Wso2 Identity Server. But please help me achieve the same with Wso2 ESB.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Where you want to add the security? What you want to secure?

I see two parts where the user security may play role in ESB:

For the carbon (management) console, I may disappoint you, that may not be so simple. See the [Custom carbon authentication](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/03/25/different-authentication-mechanism-for-wso2-carbon-management-console-and-admin-service-apis/) . It seems you need to enable other authenticators or add your own (see the file authenticators.xml, they are disabled by default) and "patch" the carbon to use it. However - for our best practices the management console (and the management services) should be not accessible from untrusted network .

If you're talking about securing the web services, this is not something an end user (person) is accessing. Ok - excluding the REST services. There are multiple options available to secure web services. From basic authentication (and username token), to STS (security token service), signing and encrypting the payload. See [Securing web services](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Securing+Proxy+Services), however here we assume some knowledge about the service security.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997175/add-secuirty-to-wso2-esb-starbucks-example
Actually this was my original question and requirement. Please have a look

Comment: Here I think you're mixing purpose of the products. I see appropriate to enforce MFA to authenticate user with the application, but in this case the REST services through ESB need to be authenticated / authorized by the application itself. If ESB is to add additional security to the REST calls, I'd go for some self-containing tokens, jush as JWT, where a proxy service could decode and validate a JWT token itself (or call a token service).